# error: expression must have class type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error

First of all i know there are other questions that are essentially the same as this one but none of the answers seem to work for me. I'm pretty new to c++ and programming in general so please describe as simply as possibly, thank you.

So I'm trying to make a simple text game and i have a couple files but when i try to use a method from a class it causes an error that says the expression must have a class type.

Here's the code.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Warrior.h"
using namespace std;


//main function
int main (void)
{
//title screen
cout<< " _____ _           _        _____         \n";
cout<< "|   __|_|_____ ___| |___   | __  |___ ___ \n";
cout<< "|__   | |     | . | | -_|  |    -| . | . |\n";
cout<< "|_____|_|_|_|_|  _|_|___|  |__|__|  _|_  |\n";
cout<< "              |_|                |_| |___|\n";
cout<< "\n\n       Enter any # to start \n ";  

int start;
anumber:
cin>> start;

if (start < 0 || start > 0)
{
    cout<< "\nWelcome to Sam Acker's simple rpg game!\n";
}

Warrior your_warrior(int health , int armor , int weapon);
your_warrior.warrior_name_function; //This is the line with the error


int exit;
cin>> exit;
return 0;
}
```

Warrior.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Warrior
{
private:
int health;
int weapon;
int armor;
std::string warrior_name;

public:
int attack();
int warrior_name_function();

Warrior(int health , int weapon , int armor);
~Warrior();
};
```

Warrior.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Warrior.h"


int Warrior::warrior_name_function()
{
std::cout<< "What would you like to name you warrior?\n";
std::cin>> Warrior::warrior_name;
return 0;
}


int Warrior::attack()
{
return 0;
}



Warrior::Warrior(int health , int armor , int weapon)
{
 health == 100;
 armor == 1;
 weapon == 16;
}


Warrior::~Warrior()
{}
```

Comment: Keep it simple, sailor: Do we really need to see your start screen in this code example? Keep it trim, keep it lean, and visitors become more keen.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry about that. kinda new here. thanks for the tip.

Comment: What's the reason for the "anumber:" label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in main()

```
Warrior your_warrior(int health , int armor , int weapon);
```

looks like you are declaring a function, not creating an instance of class `Warrior`. You should call it with some concrete values of your variables like this to create one

```
Warrior your_warrior(10,32,2);
```

or even better create some variables, set their values and pass to the function. Then call

```
your_warrior.warrior_name_function();
```

your compilation error is because it does not recognise your_warrior as a class instance but as a declaration of a function.

Comment: Thanks that helped so much it was driving me crazy.

Comment: In my case, I hadn't added an include for the header ... d'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot the parentheses when calling the name function:

```
your_warrior.warrior_name_function();
```

I would also suggest that you simply remove the destructor for the `Warrior` class: it doesn't have anything to clean up.

Comment: still didn't fix it. thanks for being so fast though.also thanks for the destructor tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
Warrior your_warrior(int health , int armor , int weapon);
```

This line declares a function `named your_warrior` that take three arguments of type `int` and returns an object of type `Warrior`.

If you remove the three `int`s it will work much better. `<g>`

And, of course, add the parentheses for the function call in the next line.

Comment: Yes, I assumed, without looking, that you had defined variables with those three names. As @mathematician1975 suggested, you can call that constructor with literal values if you want.